# Survey propagation conflicts

Tags: belief-propagation

I've been spending a lot of time trying to get survey propagation to work and I'm unsure whether I have a bug in my code or if I need to do more to my algorithm. I get a bit lost in all the heavy math involved in a lot of the papers I read about survey propagation, so maybe I've missed something.

I have a CNF that is known to be satisfiable. There's about 2.1 million clauses and about 840k variables. I believe the ratio of clause to variable is a good sign that survey propagation can solve this.

What I'm finding is that all of my surveys end up either 0 or 1. There aren't any values in between. I'm unsure whether this is a sign of having a problem. It does seem kind of suspicious.

My understanding is that I should repeat the following steps until the CNF is trivial:

1. Generate surveys
2. Generate biases
3. Pick single bias with the max diff
4. Apply bias to formula to simplify

In my case, I'm seeing a whole lot of biases with the same max diff. None of the papers I've read really seem to address whether you still need to only choose one bias or whether you could use them all as long as they have the same diff value. Ideally I'd like to use them all because I could do a massive amount of simplification prior to generating the next batch of surveys.

I have been experimenting with using all the biases vs just using one. I seem to keep ending up with variables that have contradictory values regardless of what I do.

To put it simply, should I be expecting contradictory values and, as a result, have to backtrack at that point? I'm worried about the performance of this. I got into using survey propagation because it's supposed to be good on big problems, but I don't see how that works if there's lots of backtracking going on. Perhaps it's just because I have a hard formula and it's the wrong tool for the job?